# Проверка "пустоты" ячейки

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Есть таблица, которая выглядит следующим образом: https://pastenow.ru/CV9T9

Мне нужно выбранную строку в dataGridView в C# (Windows Forms) "обрезать" и вставить таким образом, чтобы пустые ячейки не вставлялись. Другими словами, допустим, у меня есть запрос на коктейль "Белый русский" - нужно, чтобы вставились только 4 столбика из 11.
Пробовал с помощью подобного кода:

```
            myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectString); //подключение к бд

            myConnection.Open();

            textBox1.Text = product_name; //тут название коктейля
            textBox2.Text = price.ToString(); //тут его цена
            checkBox1.Checked = existence; //тут наличие в данный момент

            string query = $"SELECT * FROM ТК WHERE Товар = '{textBox1.Text}'"; //запрос на строку
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);

            command.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; //вывод в dataGridView
            myConnection.Close(); //закрытие соединения
```

Но он выводит только целую строчку. Как её можно обрезать?

Если вдруг кому-нибудь в будущем сможет это помочь, вот решение: https://pastenow.ru/CVIQR

Comment: Получить запись. Протестировать каждое поле на "пустоту" (а там может быть NULL, пустая строка, десяток пробелов, неразрывный пробел и пр.). Составить текст запроса, включающий список конкретных полей, тех, которые не пустые, а не абстрактное `SELECT * ..`. Выполнить. Вывести результат.

Comment: Альтернативно. Загрузить данные в грид как есть. Пробежаться по строке. Для всех пустых полей - установить нулевую ширину поля.

Comment: Пробую вот так проверять и удалять пустые столбцы - не работает : https://pastenow.ru/CVAUK

Comment: и даже вот так оно не хочет удалять лишние столбцы - https://pastenow.ru/CVB30

Comment: @Frehzy ну [этот](https://pastenow.ru/CVAUK) пример работать точно не будет, так как вы поставили условие при котором значение И `null` И `ToString() == ""`. А вот вторых, попробуйте у `DataGridView` вызвать `Refresh()`

Comment: Если вдруг кому-нибудь в будущем сможет это помочь, вот решение: https://pastenow.ru/CVIQR

Comment: @KuzCode - `Refresh()` в данном случае не нужен. Постоянно его лепят куда попало...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вдруг кому-нибудь в будущем сможет это помочь, вот решение: https://pastenow.ru/CVIQR

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вызов `Refresh()` не нужен! Тем более в цикле.